# Symfony 2 Production Setup Error on shared hosting - Contd

Tags: symfony, redirect, webserver, shared-hosting, symfony-2.7

Continuing on from here:

[Symfony 2 Production Setup Error: "redirected you too many times."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70586194/symfony-2-production-setup-error-redirected-you-too-many-times)

I tried some more things. I realised if I created a symlink from public_html to the web folder and then created an index.html inside the web folder. The directory structure is as follows:

```
/
|
home
|
[website_name]
|
[website_bitbucket_repo], public_html(symlink to web)
|
web
|
app.php, app_dev.php, index.html(symlink to app.php)
```

I added an index.html inside the web folder and it would finally load that page (even index.php caused: "redirected you too many times.")

I then created a symlink from index.html to app.php but I get this on loading the website homepage:

```
loadClassCache(); //$kernel = new AppCache($kernel); // When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter //Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride(); $request = Request::createFromGlobals(); $response = $kernel->handle($request); $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response); $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on'; $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
```

If I create the symlink from index.html to app_dev.php I get:

```
loadClassCache(); $request = Request::createFromGlobals(); $response = $kernel->handle($request); $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

i.e. part of the contents of the file.

I feel like I am on the right track, as I am no longer getting redirect errors but I am not sure where to go form here as to actually loading the Symfony application?

Comment: Why are you creating those symlinks? Cant you avoid it to not complicate your setup?

Comment: Do i understand correctly that if try to browse those pages then you see source code in response? Can you create simple file "test123.php" in "web" directory with following contents: `<?php echo 'it works';` and then try to open it with browser. What do you see?

Comment: u are obviously missing a .htaccess file in your web-directory, look for a symfony2 skeleton how it has to look, it will rewrite everything to index.php

Comment: @johnSmith is right. Please look at some existing symfony2 examples - like: https://github.com/numerogeek/ultimate-symfony2-boilerplate . `.htaccess` file is in: https://github.com/numerogeek/ultimate-symfony2-boilerplate/tree/master/web

Comment: Looks like some apache misconfiguration, are you by change using an ssl certificate and redirect from  http to httpS redirection directive ?